# Is it possible to read a Zend_Application configuration variable inside of a controller?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'd like to have something like a

```
webmasterEmail = blah@example.com
```

where the ErrorController sends an email if the application is running in production mode. Is it possible to just tack this on to Zend_Application's `.ini` file and retrieve the values in a controller later?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All too easy :)

```
// return all options as an array
$options = $this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap')->getOptions();

// or, specifically
$webmasterEmail = $this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap')
                       ->getOption('webmasterEmail');
```

Comment: Would `Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getParam('bootstrap');` work outside of a controller (i.e. in a model) too?

Comment: @Billy Probably. I'd make use of `Zend_Registry` in these cases though, populating it from a bootstrap `_init*` method